# Seedstack W20 and Angular 2+

Tags: angular, seedstack

Not knowing very well Seedstack W20 web framework, AFAIK this framework is built on top of AngularJS and other good frameworks. 
I'm wondering if Seedstack plans to migrate to Angular 2+
Anyone with an answer here ?

Answer (score 0):

Until about two years ago, SeedStack was a full-stack development solution, encompassing:

- Backend development with its own modular Java framework based on Google Guice, Jersey 2, Apache Shiro and other technologies.
- Frontend development with the W20 framework built on top of AngularJS 1.x.

Since then, SeedStack was repurposed as a backend-only solution with a strong focus on REST micro-services and Domain-Driven Design. It has the ability to integrate with any frontend technology.

The W20 framework lives now a [separate existence](https://w20-framework.github.io/) but will stay forever on AngularJS 1.x. SeedStack-based applications can still integrate it easily through the [W20-bridge add-on](http://seedstack.org/addons/w20-bridge/).

Now that SeedStack is open to any frontend technology, we would like to provide some official add-ons in the future to facilitate the integration of popular frontend solutions like Angular 2+ or React.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. So, if SeedStack is now fully dedicated for backend development, what are the main differences between it and other similar technologies like Microprofile or Micronaut ?